# Issue properly formatting ruby to pass rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm currently working through a set of TestFirst problems. The spec for the problem I'm working on can be found here: http://testfirst.org/live/learn_ruby/book_titles

I've tested the title method outside of the class so I know that it works, but once I place it in the class I get the following error:

```
 1) Book title should capitalize the first letter
    Failure/Error: @book.title.should == "Inferno"
    ArgumentError:
      wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title

  def initialize(title=nil)
    @title = title
  end

  def title(title)
    first_check = 0
    articles = %w{a the an in and of}
    words = title.split(" ")

    words.each do |word|

      if first_check == 0
        word.capitalize!
        first_check += 1
      elsif !articles.include?(word)
        word.capitalize!
      end

    end
    @title = words.join(" ")
  end

end
```

If someone could explain how the class should be formatted, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is right here:

```
def title(title)
```

Your `Book#title` method expects an argument but you're not giving it one in your spec:

```
@book.title.should == "Inferno"
# ----^^^^^ this method call needs an argument
```

I think you actually want a `Book#title=` method:

```
def title=(title)
  # The same method body as you already have
end
```

Then you'll use the `title` accessor method that `attr_accessor :title` supplies and assigning a new title will use your `title=` method. And since you're supplying your own mutator method, you could use [`attr_reader`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) instead:

```
class Book
  attr_reader :title

  def initialize(title=nil)
    @title = title
  end

  def title=(title)
    #...
  end
end
```

Comment: That definitely works... and now I understand what setter methods are. Thank you!